# How move map to other map

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

```
std::map<long long, std::unique_ptr<A>> listOf1;
std::map<long long, std::unique_ptr<A>> listOf2;
```

how can i add listOf1 to listOf2?
Probably it's tricky because value is unique_ptr.
Normall solution:

```
listOf2.insert(listOf1.begin(), listOf1.end());
```

doesn't work and give error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Error   C2280   'std::pair::pair(const std::pair &)': attempting to reference a deleted function    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 737 Build

Comment: What do you mean by "move"? Do you want move-assignment? Do you want to add all entries from one map to the other (and remove them from the first map)?

Comment: Something like: `listOf2.insert(std::make_move_iterator(listOf1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(listOf1.end()));` ?

Comment: I want add all elements from first map to second map and remove first map.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, it's answer for my problem :)

Comment: In C++17 there will be a much better solution.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me. I'm looking forward to C++384's telepathic compiler.

Comment: @KerrekSB what are you mind?

Comment: @21koizyd: You could say `listOf2.merge(listOf1)`, or `while (!listOf2,empty()) { listOf1.insert(listOf2.extract(listOf2.begin())); }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want:

```
listOf2.insert(std::make_move_iterator(listOf1.begin()),
               std::make_move_iterator(listOf1.end()));
listOf1.clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a standard library implementation that implements the C++17 [*node handle*](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.node) interface, you can use the [`map::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) function to splice nodes from one `map` to another.

The benefit of doing this over `map::insert` is that instead of move constructing elements, the maps will transfer ownership of nodes by simply copying over some internal pointers.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{};

int main()
{
    std::map<long long, std::unique_ptr<A>> listOf1;
    std::map<long long, std::unique_ptr<A>> listOf2;

    listOf1[10] = std::make_unique<A>();
    listOf1[20] = std::make_unique<A>();
    listOf1[30] = std::make_unique<A>();
    listOf2[30] = std::make_unique<A>();
    listOf2[40] = std::make_unique<A>();

    listOf1.merge(listOf2);
    for(auto const& m : listOf1) std::cout << m.first << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SD7shRU6KN8UL6NB)